# How prove this series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n}{\log^{10}{n}}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

prove or disprove this series 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{\log^{10}{n}}$$ is divergent?

My idea: since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{n}{\log^{10}{n}}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{\log^{10}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n^2}{10\log^9{n}}=\cdots=\infty$$
so $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{\log^{10}{n}}$$ is disconverger?

if my idea is wrong.How solve this problem? if my idea true,and this problem have other methods? Thank you

Comment: Even simpler, the terms don't converge to $0$.

Comment: $n=\Omega(\log^{10}(n))\implies \exists n :\frac{n}{\log^{10}(n)}\gt c\forall c\in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 4):

Your idea works, since you know that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. But it's even simpler, since $\frac{n}{\log_{10}(n)} \to +\infty$, so the series can't possibly converge.

Comment: I'm summing up the comments so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{n}{\log_{10}(n)}=+\infty(\not =0) $ so the series diverge

Comment: Although it doesn't change the result, the OP's logarithm is raised to power of 10, not base 10.